# how to create image uploader with preview

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, preview

I want to have a form, with multiple parts.

The first part would be images, multiple file upload with a preview of the images before actually uploading them.

The second part has various text form fields.

I have the second part built fine and working, using PHP and MySQL, and the image upload is working too. But I don't know how to show a preview of the images before submitting the form.

**EDIT:**

using code form an answer:

```
     <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
     <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

with:

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

works great, but it only shows 1 thumbnail. I want to create an image thumbnail dynamically for each file.

I'm trying :

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
          var container = $('#previews');
          var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).width(150);
          image.appendTo(container);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

with:

```
    <input type='file' name="files[]" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple />
    <div id="previews"></div>
```

which works, but how do I loop it for each file inputted?

Comment: Just add new parameter to the function, like  onchange="readURL(this, 0)  [or i in a loop],  add same identifier to the div of the image bellow the function call input field (like "previews0", or "previews"+$i,;;;;;

In js, add the parameter to function name "function readURL(input, k)" and pass it bellow to the image's div id like "previews"+k
;;;;;;
You're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at that:

http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit

from this post on stackoverflow:
[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Lucian

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show the preview before having the image on the server, except if you use java on the interface

Comment: or flash... but it seems like this is possible nowadays, take a look at my answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `HTML5` canvas and `FileReader` component

Have a look at [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/revathskumar/kGYc7/)